# read rss feed and put the result of each url in item of pivot in UWP

Tags: c#, xml, rss, pivot, win-universal-app

i want to read rss feed from different resources and then display each result in different item of a pivot ... so the resul i got so far is creating a pivot separately ... and parsing data from one rss feed ... and i'm stuck right now .. any help please ...
 here is my c# code for parsing data 
 My main page .cs

```
public RSShelperClass helperRSS = new RSShelperClass();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void feedClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            helperRSS.Go(ref Display, Value.Text);

        }
```

my helper class

```
 public  class RSShelperClass
    {
        private async void load(ItemsControl list, Uri uri)
        {
            SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
            SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri);
            if (feed != null)
            {
                foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
                {
                    list.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Go(ref ItemsControl list, string value)
        {

                try
                {
                    load(list, new Uri(value));
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                list.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want separate pivot for each list.Items? Is so you can Bind ItemSource of Pivot to list.Items. Please post your xaml for further help

Comment: thanks for the replay ..i have 3 diiferent urls to parse from .. and i want to display the result i get from these 3 in different 3 pivotItems : meaning that i need to make those 3 pivot items width and height equal to my whole available space

Comment: Parse in code behind and add that item to ObservableCollection. Bind that collection to your pivot ItemSource property

Comment: thanks i really appreciate your help ... do you have please any example ?

Answer (score 1):

you must use Binding approach to set the ItemsSource property of the 3 ListView (one ListView per PivotItem).

1.- Create the model(class with all the properties of your feed per url)

2.- create an ObservableCollection of this model and fill al the data in this collection (all data from your RSS feed)

3.- You need to add 3 pivot items to your pivot control.

4.- add 3 ListView one by ListView

5.- set the ItemsSource property of your list view with the your collections ( you need 3 ObservableCollection because you said before you have 3 urls)

6.- finally you will need to edit the item template of your ListViews.

please check this link

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/quick_thoughts/2014/06/10/data-binding-part-4-observable-collection/